# how to implement "not found" page with beamer

Tags: flutter, dart, routes, navigator, flutter-navigation

I'm using the [beamer](https://pub.dev/packages/beamer) package for flutter
and I'm trying to implement a 'not found page'

let's say that the user is on web and types on the url
http://localhost:64132/#/mdn%20vab%20ad,,,,had
I'd like to route the user to a page not found page
can you recommend a way to do that with beamer?

thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's best you use `SimpleLocationBuilder` or `BeamerLocationBuilder`. Those two will detect the `not-found` automatically, whereas a completely custom `locationBuilder` will not (in which case you would be just returning your custom `not-found` `BeamLocation` if all other checks fail).

For defining the `not-found` page, you can use either one of these properties in your `BeamerDelegate`:

- [notFoundPage](https://pub.dev/documentation/beamer/latest/beamer/BeamerDelegate/notFoundPage.html)
- [notFoundRedirectNamed](https://pub.dev/documentation/beamer/latest/beamer/BeamerDelegate/notFoundRedirectNamed.html)
- [notFoundRedirect](https://pub.dev/documentation/beamer/latest/beamer/BeamerDelegate/notFoundRedirect.html) (only if you're not using `SimpleLocationBuilder`)